# Reached the max retries per request limit (which is 20). BullMQ NestJS

Tags: nestjs, bullmq

I have configured BullMQ in my project. I can use it on local but getting this error when it's deployed on server.

```
Reached the max retries per request limit (which is 20). Refer to "maxRetriesPerRequest" option for details.
```

TLS is enabled as well. Not sure what's causing the failure, any ideas?

Comment: perhaps you should refer to "maxRetriesPerRequest" option for details? do you use an api-key?